# What "algorithm" are carnivorous larvae using when foraging?

Tags: entomology, predation

What algorithms are carnivorous larvae (lady bugs like Adalia bipunctata, Coccinella septempunctata, common green lacewing (Chrysoperla carnea) or hoverfly (Syrphus)) using as they are foraging for aphids?

Is it just random walk or something more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that when you say algorithms, you mean the forms of innate behavior an organism may have relating to their senses (e.g. when sunlight is detected by a worm through the photoreceptors in their skin, it will move towards the opposite direction of the source of light to stay in their preferred environment).

These mentioned species of insects are very different taxonomically, but their number of [sensory organs](https://www.slideshare.net/ARUN5218/sensory-organs-in-insects) are for most part similar including during larval stages.

Examples of innate behavioural responses seen in invertebrates include **taxis** and **kinesis**.

**Taxis** is a change in movement in response to an environmental stimulus – either towards (positive) or away (negative)

**Kinesis** is a change in the rate of activity in response to an environmental stimulus

So, when talking about rough algorithms, when a larva detects a particular stimulus (e.g. chemicals of prey via chemoreceptors),  The organism will either have a 1 or a -1 value for Taxis response (e.g. it runs towards or away from the prey), and a rate of activity relative to taxis which represents kinesis (e.g. it gradually moves faster towards the prey as the chemical stimulus becomes stronger (meters per hour for example).

So, you could say that the theoretical formula/algorithm for hunting prey relating to the chemoreceptors as an example would be:

*Taxis ('1' or '-1' to symbolize moving towards or away from a prey) multiplied by the number of 'prey' chemicals received by the chemoreceptors equaling the strength of the larva's response which could be (as an example) translated to the velocity of larva*

Of course all the other senses such as photoreceptors and the chordotonal organ (vibration sensor) must be considered and I couldn't find any *actual* algorithm for how these species hunt. This is just a way to percieve how insects both in and past their larval stages respond to stimuli through their innate behaviour.

Comment: By "Algorithm" I mean: Suppose you want to implement an algorithm on a computer that indistinguishably mimics the animal's behaviour provided they get the same input information, i.e. no mathematical / statistical analysis (or other mathematical approaches for that matter) is able to distinguish the outputs of either algorithm. Given such a setting, what algorithm will the programmer get? Just random walk with specific average path length (which may depend on the habitus of the plant being foraged on) or something more or less efficient, and what algorithm is it specifically?

Comment: Are you saying that it's not known what algorithm(s) -- with "algorithm" according to your definition or my definition from my other comment at your disposal) -- these animals are "using"? Is it a (current) research topic?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not experienced enough to know whether there is an algorithm that can "indistinguishably mimic an animal's behaviour provided they get the same input information" Animals in general have so many senses and chemical reactions that determine what they next action will be. As far as I know, perfectly simulating most if not all organisms is currently not an achieved goal as of yet.
If it's any help... larvae usually wonder randomly at a more or less steady pace until they sense the chemical signature of a prey/food.